# How to send mail on click without present mfmailviewcontroller in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to send my  UILabel's text data as a message body to specified email address in text field .BT when I am trying to use MessageUI framework using mfmailviewcontroller delegate it will present its own view controller and after click on send button which is available in mfviewcontroller mail will be sent.

My requirement is to send mail directly on click of send button without **Presenting** mfmodel view controller screen.Can anyone please hep me for the same ?
.I searched for this BT not found any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS/apple framework doesnt allow application to directly send email without users explicite permission. so you Have to open the compose view controller.

To achive as like above you need to call web service in which web service will send email and you need to pass the email as the web params.